# ¿Uso de this para que almacene el incremento del contador?

Tags: c#

El problema es el siguiente, cuando ejecuto el programa el método Añadir() me permite agregar una canción pero cuando ejecuto el método Mostrar() para ver las canciones almacenadas, no me sale ninguna como si no estuviera leyendo la variable contador que se incremento para recorrer la Struct, Alguien podria ayudarme a conectar los métodos correctamente para que funcionen?, Muchas Gracias.

Aquí el código:

Aca inicio la clase canciones

```
public class Canciones 
{    
    public Canciones (int contador) 
    {
        contador = 0;
    }
    int contador;
    struct tipoCanciones { 
        public string nombre;
        public string album; 
        public int año;
        public string artista;       
    } 
    tipoCanciones [] c = new tipoCanciones[100];
```

Aca supuesta mente asigno contador a this.contador

```
public void setContador(int contador){
    this.contador = contador;    
}
```

Este es el método añadir, cuando añades una canción supuestamente la guarda, pero a la hora de ejecutar el método Mostrar todas las canciones(Mostrar()) entonces no muestra las canciones almacenadas y no encuentro aún como conectar los métodos:

```
public void Añadir(){ 
    Console.WriteLine("ESTE PROGRAMA LE PERMITIRA GUARDAR HASTA 100 CANCIONES");
    for(int i=0; i<c.Length; i++)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el nombre de la cancion");
        c[i].nombre = (Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el album de la cancion");
        c[i].album = (Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el año de la cancion");
        c[i].año = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Digite el artista de la cancion");
        c[i].artista = (Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Desea seguir guardando canciones?: SI/NO");
        contador++; 
        string r = Console.ReadLine();
        if(r=="No" || r=="no" || r=="NO")
        {
            Menu();
        }
    }
}
```

// Este es el método buscar púes acá lo que intento hacer es comparar si el titulo de una cancion o el nombre de un artista se encuentran almacenada en la estructura:

```
    public void Buscar()
    { 
     Console.WriteLine("Digite el artista de la cancion a buscar");
     string art = Console.ReadLine();
     Console.WriteLine("Digite el titulo de la cancion a buscar");
     string titulo = Console.ReadLine();

     for(int i=0; i<c.Length; i++){ 

     if (c[i].artista.Contains(art) || c[i].nombre.Contains(titulo) ){  

     Console.WriteLine("La cancion se encuentra en la posicion{0}", i);
     Console.WriteLine("Los datos completos de la cancion son:");

     Console.WriteLine("Nombre: {0}", c[i].nombre);
     Console.WriteLine("Album: {0}",c[i].album);
     Console.WriteLine("Año: {0}", c[i].año);
     Console.WriteLine("Artista: {0}", c[i].artista);

     Console.ReadLine();
    }

     Console.WriteLine("Desea seguir buscando canciones?: SI/NO");
     string r = Console.ReadLine();

      if(r=="No" || r=="no" || r=="NO")
     {
      Menu();
     }

       }
     }
```

Acá es donde tengo el problema de que la Struc no me muestra ninguna canción almacenada:

```
    public void Mostrar(){

    Console.WriteLine("Desea ver las canciones almacenadas en su lista? digite SI/NO");

    string resp = Console.ReadLine();

    if (resp =="SI" || resp == "si" || resp == "Si"){
          for (int j = 0; j <= contador; j++)
           {

            Console.WriteLine("[*[*[*[*[ Las canciones almacenadas en su lista son *]*]*]*]*] ", j+1);
            Console.WriteLine("Nombre: {0}", c[j].nombre);
            Console.WriteLine("Album: {0}", c[j].album);
            Console.WriteLine("Año: {0}", c[j].año);
            Console.WriteLine("Artista: {0}", c[j].artista);
            }
       }
      }
```

Y aca esta el metodo Menú el cual muestra el menú, el cual me muestra todas las opciones y eso:

```
    public void Menu(){

    Canciones obj = new Canciones(0);

    Console.WriteLine("BIENVENIDO AL MENU DEL PROGRAMA CANCIONES");
    Console.WriteLine("1). Añadir una nueva cancion");
    Console.WriteLine("2). Mostrar el titulo de todas las canciones");
    Console.WriteLine("3). Buscar una cancion");
    Console.WriteLine("4). Salir");

     string r = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (r) {

        case "1":

         obj.Añadir();

        break;

        case "2":

         obj.Mostrar();
        break;

        case "3":

        obj.Buscar();

        break;

        case "4":

        break;

        default:

        Console.WriteLine("Ha salido del programa");

        break;
       }
    }


    public static void Main(){

    Canciones obj = new Canciones(0);

    obj.Menu();
     }
    }
```

Comment: supongo que esto es un ejercicio y veo varias cosas confunsas.. lo primero que no encuentro es que es c.. donde esta definido?

Comment: Cada vez que llamas a menú vuelves a inicializar la variable del objeto canciones, entonces cada vez que agregas y sales llamando a menú vuelves a perder todo lo guardado.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Como te mencionaron en el comentario anterior cada vez que se ejecuta el método Menu() creas una instancia nueva de Canciones por lo que todos los datos que ingresaste se pierden y el contador queda en 0.

Debes declarar e instanciar la variable fuera del método Menu();

```
Canciones obj = new Canciones(0);
public void Menu(){

Console.WriteLine("BIENVENIDO AL MENU DEL PROGRAMA CANCIONES");
Console.WriteLine("1). Añadir una nueva cancion");
Console.WriteLine("2). Mostrar el titulo de todas las canciones");
Console.WriteLine("3). Buscar una cancion");
Console.WriteLine("4). Salir");
…
```

De esta forma al terminar de agregar las canciones y volver al método Menu tendrás todos los datos ingresados mas el valor del contador.

Comment: Ademas agregaria que canciones no deberia ser una clase, si no solo una lista, y la clase deberia ser el struct que tiene adentro.